# How to add rests on top of notes and finger roll notations in Guitar Pro 7?

Tags: notation, guitar-pro

[image: rest]

[image: finger roll]

Please help, i'm really lost and still learning the basics.

Comment: Could it be that guitar pro doesn't have different layers?  I can't find any solution on this site: https://blog.guitar-pro.com/2019/01/tuto-10-tips-to-give-a-professional-look-to-your-scores-in-guitar-pro/

Comment: There are. It is called "voices" in the guitar pro world

Comment: For the lower voice just add "let ring" to the bass notes

Answer (score 1):

Create different tracks:

*Guitar Pro supports more than one "voice" for each track. 
Each Guitar Pro staff contains two independent voices in the case of GP5, and 4 for GP6. This type of notation is thus closer to the standards of musical notation.
To edit a voice, choose the "Edit > Voices > Edit Voice 1" or "Edit > Voices > Edit Voice 2" menus (or voice 3 or 4 in GP6). 
For more clarity in Guitar Pro 5, you can choose to grey out the voice you're not editing at the moment: "Edit > Voices > Gray Inactive Voice".
In Guitar Pro 6, simply choose to work on Voice 1, 2, 3, or 4, or in multitrack mode.*

[link](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/200633461-GP6-How-can-I-type-in-two-notes-played-at-the-same-time-but-with-different-duration-values-)

Answer (score 0):

In your music programme you will find that you have different layers available when writing music on one stave.  Your examples have 2 layers.  The programme that I use allows up to 4 different layers.  Your first layer has all the notes stems pointing up, and the second layer they are pointing down, for clarity.  For finger roll notations, do you have a help manual?  That would show you were and how to write these.  Look up different music layers there too.  Hope that helps.

Comment: yes I tried looking but nothing mentioned a finger roll :(